# Loud POP from audio - need more details

Tags: sound, kubuntu

Kubuntu 18.04

As has been noted in many other posts: there is a loud POP from the audio system on boot, re-boot, and in my case whenever I pause audio for more than a few minutes and restart OR when I switch between sources (spotify, YouTube, desktop player) OR Mute/unMute the audio OR adjust the volume.

I found a txt file with the config settings that talks about setting power saving options for the audio system and says

```
AC97 and HD-audio drivers have the automatic power-saving mode.
This feature is enabled via Kconfig CONFIG_SND_AC97_POWER_SAVE
and CONFIG_SND_HDA_POWER_SAVE options, respectively.
```

Great. I  install kconfig, start through the various help screens, but I can't figure out how to use it. Later the file says

```
The power_save option is exported as writable.  This means you can
adjust the value via sysfs on the fly.  For example, to turn on the
automatic power-save mode with 10 seconds, write to
/sys/modules/snd_ac97_codec/parameters/power_save (usually as root):

    # echo 10 > /sys/modules/snd_ac97_codec/parameters/power_save
```

but when I try I get

```
bash: /sys/modules/snd_ac97_codec/parameters/power_save: No such file or directory
```

Help me out here. How do I get rid of the POPs?

Answer (score 0):

[note: you need to be root for this].

Open file in console using: sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
[or, use Dolphin, open with Kate.]

Add the following line at the bottom of the page:

options snd-hda-intel power_save=0 power_save_controller=N

save and reboot.